# ReentrantLock.tryLock() not locking

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I think I just am not seeing something as I've gotten this to work in the past.

My lock isn't holding an exclusive lock, and when a new instance of the object is created, `tryLock` returns true and another `TimerTask` is scheduled.

```
public class A {
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static Lock clean_lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String,B> _b_dict = new ConcurrentHashmap<String,B>();

    public A() {
        if(clean_lock.tryLock()) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTaskThread(), new Date(), 60000);
        }
    }

    //Various NON static methods 
    // use an iterator at one point so they must be NON static

    class TimerTaskThread extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            //delete old stuff in _b_dict
        }
    }
}

//sample usage
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        A a = new A();
        a.contains(new B());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a lock?  Why not initialise you static values in a static block? I can't see where it would create a second task.

Comment: Does it really look like that? Are you never releasing the lock with `clean_lock.unlock()`?

Comment: @JohnVint I believe this is so it only creates one task ever.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok thats what I was assuming, figure I ask in case of programming error.

Comment: The plan was to not unlock() so I only ever schedule one clean up thread. If there is a better approach (i'm sure there is) i'd be open to that as an answer as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you creating the other `A` instance from another thread? Because if you're creating both instances from the same thread, then, the lock being reentrant, `tryLock` obviously returns true.

If you really want to schedule from the constructor, and not from a static block, you should use a static `AtomicBoolean` variable and only schedule the timer if `compareAndSet(false, true)` returns true.

Comment: It's being created in the same object ( call it class C), and C is being instantiated multiple times.
Let me trace C in the debugger, think you probably nailed it.

Answer (score 4):

For what purpose are you using the lock here; just to ensure that `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` is called only once (the first time the constructor of `A` is called)?

You could do it in a static initializer block instead, so that you don't need the lock at all:

```
public class A {
    private static final Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,B> _b_dict = new ConcurrentHashmap<String,B>();

    static {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTaskThread(), new Date(), 60000);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

If you use a static block, the scheduling will be done when the class is initialized (after it's loaded), rather than the first time you create an instance of it.

Another possibility is to use an `AtomicBoolean`:

```
public class A {
    private static final Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static final AtomicBoolean initDone = new AtomicBoolean();
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,B> _b_dict = new ConcurrentHashmap<String,B>();

    public A() {
        if (!initDone.getAndSet(true)) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTaskThread(), new Date(), 60000);
        }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would write it.

```
public class A {
    private static final ExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledExecutorService();
    private static final ConcurrentMap<String,B> _b_dict = new ConcurrentHashmap<String,B>();
    static {
       service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               cleanUp();
           }
       }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    static void cleanUp() {
       // remove old entries
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what im going to change it too, but unfortunately JB found the real problem with the lock.

Comment: Its a good thing he found it, but the real answer is you don't need it.